# python - single item tuple throws exception in for statement

Tags: python, exception, dictionary

Im curious as to why this happens. Im using Mako templates to iterate over a tuple, that contains a number of number of dictionaries, that in turn contain link information:

```
links = (
        {
            'path' : request.route_url('home'),
            'text' : 'Home'
        },
        {
            'path' : "http://www.microsoft.com",
            'text' : "Microsoft"
        }
    )
```

if i send the above to the view, everything works as expected, the links are displayed. If i remove the second link however:

```
links = (
            {
                'path' : request.route_url('home'),
                'text' : 'Home'
            }
)
```

i get an exception: `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

if i put a comma after the end of the dictionary, things start working again. Can anyone explain what is going on?

*Edit* Mako template snippet

```
<nav>

       % for link in links:
        <a href="${link['path']}">${link['text']}</a>
       % endfor

      </nav>
```

Comment: Can you show how the Mako template looks? How the iterating code is written out?

Comment: @jochenritzel nailed it. Though, you can also explicitly use the `tuple()` builtin to avoid the implicit syntax quirks. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if i put a comma after the end of the dictionary, things start working
>   again. Can anyone explain what is going on?

The **comma** makes the tuple. Without it you just have a single value in brackets.

```
x = ({}) # brackets around a dict
x = {}, # a 1-tuple
x = ({},) # a 1-tuple in brackets
```

Often it appears that the brackets are the notation for tuples, because they appear together so often. That's only because for syntactic reasons, you often need the brackets when writing a tuple.

When you write `links = ({ ... })` you have only a dictionary, not a tuple. Python loops over it's keys, so each `link` is a string, which you try to index by another string, resulting in the exception.